# How do I get a specific string UNTIL a specific character out of a string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have this string:

Blah blah blah - 2389023823

I want to grab everything to the LEFT of the dash:

"Blah blah blah"

How do I go about doing this?

I'm assuming I would have to do `LEFT()` with `ChARINDEX() + LEN()` somehow but I'm having difficulty.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difficulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) and [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('-', ColumnName)-1)
FROM TableName
```

Comment: this did the trick. I just had to add -2 at the end so that I don't grab the space :)

Answer (score 0):

declare @string varchar(50) 
set @string = 'Blah blah blah - 2389023823'

select SUBSTRING(@string, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', @string) - 1, -1)) as ResultingString

Answer (score 0):

USE RTRIM() and Left() with CHARINDEX() in SQL Server

```
RTRIM(LEFT(columnName, CHARINDEX('-', columnName)-1))
```